# How can i undo `git add` on a newly created file, without affecting other added files?

Tags: git

in working directory, I created a new file, and made changes to some existing files. Then I run `git add` on the new file and the modified existing files.
i haven't run `git commit` on the above files yet.

Now i would like to remove and discard the new file, without affecting other added and modified files. How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`git reset path-of-file` will remove from index, won't touch anything else (won't remove the file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`git rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

```
git rm path/to/your_file.ext
```

Note this will remove your file from disk as well.

Comment: If you want to remove the file even from file system, this is the answer.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. You need to use `git rm -f` to remove the file from disk, or `git rm --cached` to remove it from the index only.

Comment: You could also just `git rm /file/path` then `git checkout /file/path` nbd

Answer (score 0):

Typing `git status` will tell you what to do:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   a
```

Or in case you have both modified and new files:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   a
    new file:   b
```

So, either use **`git rm --cached <file>...`** or **`git reset HEAD <file>...`** to unstage.